# exporting Flurry.com data

Tags: iphone, flurry

I have been using Flurry.com to capture my analytical data for my iPhone app.  I send them custom event information about what is going on in my application (registration/login/etc).  I pass extra information with these events.  Now I want to access this information and analyze it.  How do I do that?

On their website I can see small 'pages' of information captured from my app.  I can even 'export to CSV' a small 'page' of this data.  But I do not see a way to export all of the data for a given period of time.  Am I missing something?

I found api.flurry.com RESTful API today, but again it looks like I can only make two different calls that seem kind of useless (AppMetrics/AppInfo) and only return information for canned metrics.  I really want to get at the custom events and custom event data that I sent to them.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There now appears to be [EventMetrics](http://wiki.flurry.com/index.php?title=EventMetrics) API call, it allows you to request information about your Events.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't looked into this lately.  Hopefully this will provide me what I am looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I received the following response from Flurry:

*I apologize for the inconvenience. We will eventually be expanding Flurry's API functionality to include events data. But until that occurs you should be able to access your event's data via Flurry's CSV files.*

It looks like my data is stuck inside of Flurry.com right now.  I think I better re-think my analytics strategy.  I need my data out of Flurry.com and into my own data warehouse!

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Flurry has now implemented its events data API. However, if you want to do custom analytics on the custom data that you send, you will probably be disappointed. The output of a call to the events data API is a summary, not your original logs.